# relación circular

Tags: mysql, modelorelacional, base-de-datos

Buenos días quisiera saber si necesariamente, una base datos que tenga relaciones circulares se considera como mal diseñada, tengo base de datos de colegio donde los alumnos puede ver la misma materia en diferentes grados es decir ejemplo el de primer grado puede ver con el quinto grado matemáticas y se me arma problema debido que en horario necesito el id de cual matricula para eso armo disponibles que es como el grupo de asignaciones disponibles

matricula->Grado->asignaciones

matricula->matricula_horarios-horarios->diponibles->asignaciones

disponibles es como la relación que me permite listar las asignaciones correctas de acuerdo grado  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que es matricula? y que es grados? y porque tienen una relacion? si matricula es una materia (aca podemos tener diferencias de idioma) y el grado es el año para el cual existe, en realidad no deberian estar separadas y deberia existir una materia por año. O sea deberia existir matematica 1 (digamos para el primer año) y matematica 5 (digamos para el quinto año). Aparte de eso, las relaciones circulares no implican una mala DB, ya que algunas DB a veces no hay que verlas como a un todo, si no por pedazos.

Comment: si deben diferenciarse por que a pesar que las vean juntas las materias el diseño curricular temáticas son distintas en diseño pedagógico el modelo en cual profesor puede dictar personalizad amente en el mismo espacio el chico se matricula en grado de 0 a 5 que a su vez estas tiene un asignaciones con temáticas distintas pero me preocupa la circularidad que hay en asignaciones ya que al poder mezclar las clases de matemáticas necesito validar que realmente si la pueda tomar chico para eso se crea disponibilidad y es donde se crea la circularidad

Comment: ay perdon.. no entendi nada :( no son materias diferentes?